# Get different values from repeating item JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this json derived dict:

```
{
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "Jengas",
            "time": 166,
            "uid": "177098244407558145",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "- k",
            "time": 20,
            "uid": "199295228664872961",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "name": "MAD MARX",
            "time": "0",
            "uid": "336539711785009153",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "name": "loli",
            "time": 20,
            "uid": "366299640976375818",
            "id": 4
        },
        {
            "name": "Woona",
            "time": 20,
            "uid": "246996981178695686",
            "id": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the "time" from everybody in the list and use it with sort.

So the result I get has this:

```
TOP 10:
Jengas: 166
Loli: 20
```

My first try is to list different values from repeating item.

Right now the code is:

```
with open('db.json') as json_data:
    topvjson = json.load(json_data)
    print(topvjson)
    d = topvjson['stats'][0]['time']
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract the `stats` list, apply `sort` to it with the appropriate key:

```
from json import loads

data = loads("""{
  "stats": [{
    "name": "Jengas",
    "time": 166,
    "uid": "177098244407558145",
    "id": 1
  }, {
    "name": "- k",
    "time": 20,
    "uid": "199295228664872961",
    "id": 2
  }, {
    "name": "MAD MARX",
    "time": "0",
    "uid": "336539711785009153",
    "id": 3
  }, {
    "name": "loli",
    "time": 20,
    "uid": "366299640976375818",
    "id": 4
  }, {
    "name": "Woona",
    "time": 20,
    "uid": "246996981178695686",
    "id": 5
  }]
}""")

stats = data['stats']
stats.sort(key = lambda entry: int(entry['time']), reverse=True)

print("TOP 10:")
for entry in stats[:10]:
  print("%s: %d" % (entry['name'], int(entry['time'])))
```

This prints:

```
TOP 10:
Jengas: 166
- k: 20
loli: 20
Woona: 20
MAD MARX: 0
```

Note that your `time` is neither an integer nor string: there are both `0` and `"0"` in the dataset. That's why you need the conversion `int(...)`.

Comment: It starts with smallest values. And how to get hightst value first?

Comment: try this: `print(sorted(data['stats'], key=lambda item : int(item['time']), reverse=True)[:10])`

Comment: @Jengas add `sort( ... , reverse = True)`, as Sphinx said. Updated answer.

Comment: Getting this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jengas\Desktop\Voice_stats\bot.py", line 93, in <module>
    stats.sort(key = lambda entry: entry['time'], reverse=True)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Jengas As I said, your data seems a little bit broken. If you want to tolerate `"0"` instead of `0` in `time`, then you should replace every `entry['time']` by `int(entry['time'])`. Updated again.

Comment: @Jengas Also added the `TOP 10`-selection (it was in your code, I assume that you want only the first ten entries, not the entire database). Does it still not work if you use it in your project for some reason?

Comment: @Jengas I asked because I couldn't explain accept/unaccept, thought that I broke something in the last edit...

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the list of dict values like:

#### Code:

```
top_three = [(x[1], -x[0]) for x in sorted(
    (-int(user['time']), user['name']) for user in stats['stats'])][:3]
```

This works by taking the time and the name and building a tuple.  The tuples can the be sorted, and then the names can be extracted (via: `x[1]`) after the sort.

#### Test Code:

```
stats = {
    "stats": [{
        "name": "Jengas",
        "time": 166,
        "uid": "177098244407558145",
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "name": "- k",
        "time": 20,
        "uid": "199295228664872961",
        "id": 2
    }, {
        "name": "MAD MARX",
        "time": "0",
        "uid": "336539711785009153",
        "id": 3
    }, {
        "name": "loli",
        "time": 20,
        "uid": "366299640976375818",
        "id": 4
    }, {
        "name": "Woona",
        "time": 20,
        "uid": "246996981178695686",
        "id": 5
    }]
}

top_three = [x[1] for x in sorted(
    (-int(user['time']), user['name']) for user in stats['stats'])][:3]

print(top_three)
```

#### Results:

```
[('Jengas', 166), ('- k', 20), ('Woona', 20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it using the built-in [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function:

```
data = {
    "stats": [
        {
            "name": "Jengas",
            "time": 166,
            "uid": "177098244407558145",
            "id": 1
        },
        {   
           etc ...
        }
    ]
}

print('TOP 3')
sorted_by_time = sorted(data['stats'], key=lambda d: int(d['time']), reverse=True)

for i, d in enumerate(sorted_by_time, 1):
    if i > 3: break
    print('{name}: {time}'.format(**d))
```

Output:

```
TOP 3
Jengas: 166
- k: 20
loli: 20
```

Comment: Ah, `sorted` immediately returns something meaningful! I always trip up on the strange side-effecty `.sort`-method that doesn't return anything. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrey: You could also do something like this with the list's `sort()` method. Its main "side-effect" is that it sorts the list _in-place_ — which means it doesn't return anything (but does change the list).